# how glibc manages buffers?

Tags: c, glibc

I would like to understand how buffering works in glibc for `fread()` and `fwrite()` functions. Lets say, I am reading and writing a file at random positions with `fread()` and `fwrite()`. When I read at certain offset, the blocks involved in the read call are copied into glibc buffer, correct? Then if I read at another position in file, this buffer is replaced with new data, is this how buffering works in glibc ? I mean, there is only 1 buffer and the data is copied from kernel to user space on any `fread()`/`fwrite()` that is outside the buffer space.

The functionality I am looking, is that glibc would have N number of buffers, and would be able to save blocks I am reading in its internal space, so when a random `fread()` has to access certain position in the file, it wouldn't have to make a `read()` syscall to read the disk block again. Is this functionality implemented in glibc, or maybe another libc implementation?

Comment: I don't know and you should not rely on it either. But perhaps this would help you: if you plan on randomly reading from file, `mmap()` it. In the very least, you are telling the kernel your intention and the Linux kernel _may_ have implemented what you are talking about.

Comment: Nulik: Shahbaz and MattBianco got the important part of the answer right: It's none of your business, as arrogant as it might sound. It could be implemented this way today and another way tomorrow, whatever the code maintainer considers the most efficient implementation he can do for the general case.

Comment: @Shahbaz thank for the idea, I checked it and I see that with mmap I will still impose the window size of the file where to read or write. The problem is , I dont know what access pattern will be on that file, and so I am looking for glibc to cache the most used disk blocks, this way it will adjust itself for the access pattern of the application

Comment: I think maybe I should drop the use of glibc at all, because I can go with io_submit and it will use linux internal block cache, so the only thing i need to do is to group all read/write calls in one io_submit and this will compensate for the time to issue a syscall. maybe it will even faster than with glibc because buffer copying from kernel to user space won't be necessary like when doing single fread()s/fwrite()s

Comment: @Nulik, doing things low-level like you said are likely to give your an improvement in speed, if done right. However, I suggest writing a quick test and see the actual benefit. Hard disks themselves cache your accessed pages and I suspect the Linux kernel also does that. So in the end using glibc may end up being just as fast.

Comment: @Nulik: Talking as a long-time maintenance coder, the general idea is to use standard functionality (e.g. `fread()` / `fwrite()`) unless you have *proof* (i.e. profiler output) that you are indeed *having* a bottleneck in your application performance caused by *exactly* these functions. It is *very* easy to do "sophisticated" low-level coding, and eventually ending up with *worse* performance, not to mention a maintenance nightmare, than you would have had with generic code. In so far, MattBianco's answer is spot-on.

Comment: @Nulik Could you please explain about the problem with the window size?

Answer (score 1):

It would be really dangerous to rely on internal implementation of any API. Don't make any other assumptions, but only those that can be taken from documentation/specification/manual pages. Other things could stop being current and you wouldn't even know this, as internal changes wouldn't affect documented behaviour of API.

Answer (score 0):

As a programmer using the standard library, you shouldn't care about it's implementation details.

The source for GNU libc is [freely available](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/download.html) if you wish to study it's current implementation.

That said, the operating system handles I/O buffers efficiently so `fread()` and `fwrite()` typically doesn't have to.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It would however suite as a comment.

Comment: @alk I wouldn't agree. If someone asks - how can I jump from the building? we wouldn't give any hints, just say - don't. That's what is going on in case of this question.

Comment: -1 for saturating the site with useless replies, this is not what I asked

Comment: @Nulik Maybe this answer is useless for you, but it might be useful for others, perhaps less skilled developers. Just don't use `fread()` and `fwrite()` if you have extreme caching requirements.